# Break the character values into multiple names in SAS

Tags: variables, sas

Suppose I have a data set as follows

```
data mydat; 
  input samplename$ value;
  datalines;
  AA:77:D1 45
  BB:08:D3 50
;
run;
```

I would like to separate the 'samplename' variable values into three part with three new variable.
Expected outcome is
[image]

Comment: Did you try to use the SCAN() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular task you can use the folowing code:

```
data mydat; 
  length  v1 v2 v3 $200; 
  input v1 v2 v3 value;
  infile cards dlm=": ";
  datalines;
  AA:77:D1 45
  BB:08:D3 50
;
run;
```

Tom has absolutely correctly suggested more traditional and might be flexible for the changes way:

```
data mydat; 
  length samplename v1 v2 v3 $200; 
  input samplename$ value;
  v1 = scan (samplename, 1, ':');
  v2 = scan (samplename, 2, ':');
  v3 = scan (samplename, 3, ':');
  datalines;
  AA:77:D1 45
  BB:08:D3 50
;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

For the case of **samplename** data values always having three parts you can specify `dlm=': '`

Example:

```
data want; 
  infile datalines dlm=': ';
  input (var1-var3) ($) value;
  datalines;
  AA:77:D1 45
  BB:08:D3 50
;
run;
```